# Find if path exist or not in maze c++

Tags: c++, c++11, backtracking

My code is giving me runtime error. I can't figure it out how to resolve it?
It's not even working for smaller matrix 4 X 4 . Matrix size for the problem is not more than 20 x 20.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a[20][20];
bool findpath(int ar[][20],int i,int j,int size)
{
    if (ar[i][j]==0 || i>(size-1) || j>(size-1) || i<0 || j<0)
        return false;
    if (ar[i][j]==2)
        return true;
    if ((findpath(ar,i+1,j,size)) || (findpath(ar,i,j+1,size)) 
    || (findpath(ar,i-1,j,size)) || (findpath(ar,i,j-1,size)))
        return true;
    return false;
}
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {   int n;
        cin>>n;

        int r,c;

        //size = n;
        for(int i =0 ;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                cin>>a[i][j];
                if (a[i][j]==1)
                   { r=i;
                    c=j;
                   }
            }

        }
        //cout<<r<<c;
        bool b = findpath(a,r,c,n);
        if (b)
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
1
4
3 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 1 0 3 0 2 3 3
```

**Output:**

```
YES
```

But I am getting `Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)`

Comment: If `i` or `j` is negative then the first part of the condition `ar[i][j]==0` results in undefined behavior. Switch to `if (i<0 || j<0 || i>(size-1) || j>(size-1) || ar[i][j]==0) return false;` instead.

Comment: @DanielLangr still getting that error.

Comment: It was not an answer, I just pointed to undefined behavior in your code. I think there are more problems with you algorithm. For instance, how do you avoid it to go there and back forever between two adjacent fields/array elements? I think you shold never visit a field that has already been visited before. Such as in `findpath(ar,i+1,j,size)` you shoudn't invoke `findpath(ar,i-1,j,size)`, which you actually do.

Comment: If you have a `SEGV`, you have a core file (or can get one by setting eg. `ulimit -c unlimited` and re-running). If you have a core file of a program built with debug symbols, you can load it in gdb and see exactly where it crashed and why. You can also run the program under `valgrind` or build it with an address sanitizer if your compiler has one. Debugging is just one of those things you need to learn.

Comment: @DanielLangr I added ar[i][j]==1 in that condition now it's working but getting wrong answer now . :/

Comment: What are the rules. What do 3 and 0 mean? 1 is start and 2 is end?

Comment: @ThomasSablik 0 means wall , 3 means blank cell ,1 is start , 2 is end. practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-whether-path-exist

Comment: You should use maps of the maze to avoid circles. E. g. for input `1 1 2 3 1` you will generate an endless recursion. You will go up and down until you reach the maximum amount of recursions. If there is a SIGSEGV with your provided input, I can't find it since you need only one step to finish. Provide other input, if you need more help.

Comment: @user7952860 -- If you're going to post questions concerning "online judge" questions, take the time to post code that removes input statements and instead, hard-code the data into the program.  Your post reduces down to [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/320e357af4e25c66).  Also, work with that example to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @user7952860 I don't think that condition changes anything. It just avoid going back to the initial field, but does not avoid going back and forth between 2 blank cells with values 3. Use pen and paper or a debugger and check how `findpath` is called.

Comment: @user7952860: With the condition `ar[i][j]==1` your program stops at the start field since you start the search for the path with `findpath(a,r,c,n)` where `r` and `c` are the coordinates of the start field. This will yield `false` in every case.

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes it's giving me false in all the cases but if I don't consider it then it will give time limit exceeded and hence won't produce anything. There is endless loop going on if path is not found . I cant think of any solution to terminate it .

Comment: @user7952860 that is why you need a to keep a visited set as I mentioned.

Comment: @SamerTufail: thanx for pointing out that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the order of evaluation of your statement `if (ar[i][j]==0 || i>(size-1) || j>(size-1) || i<0 || j<0)`. You will access ar[i][j] to evaluate the first expression even if `i` is out of bounds or `j` is out of bounds. It should be in the order so that when a short circuit does happen in the `if` condition you are safe/does not result in undefined behaviour for example:

`if (i < 0 || i >= size || j < 0 || j >= size || ar[i][j]==0)`. Now if `i < 0` it shorcircuits and does not need to check the rest and does not evaluate `ar[i][j]`.

As you mentioned this is not working, here is a working version which I will explain. First I have changed your C style arrays to vectors and rather I use those to get row and col sizes. I also removed your inputs from users which you can add in later and helps keep the problem simple.

```
#include <vector>
bool findpath(vector<vector<int>>ar,int i,int j,vector<vector<int>>& visited)
{

    if (i < 0 || i >= ar.size() || j < 0 || j >= ar[0].size() || ar[i][j] == 0 || visited[i][j]) return false;

    if (ar[i][j]==2) return true;

    visited[i][j] = true;
    if(findpath(ar,i+1,j,visited) || findpath(ar,i,j+1,visited) || findpath(ar,i-1,j,visited) || findpath(ar,i,j-1,visited)) return true;
    visited[i][j] = false;

    return false;
}
int main() {
        const int rows = 3;
        const int cols = 3;
        vector<vector<int>> arr = {{ 0 , 3 , 2 },
                                   { 3 , 3 , 0 },
                                   { 1 , 3 , 0 }};

        vector<vector<int>> visited(rows,vector<int>(cols,false));
        bool b = findpath(arr,1,1,visited);
        if (b)
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

In the main function I have just used a `vector<vector<int>>` to describe a maze which was in the link you posted. The `i` and `j` are the starting points in the example below that is `1` and `1`. There is also a `visited` 2D array same as the maze. This stops you from going in an infinite recursion by marking the spots you have already covered and if they dont work out you set `vector[i][j] = false` to backtrack. Lastly if any of your arrangements returns a valid result we return else we just return false.

You can view this demo [live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/703c768a2d41c818)

You also mention that `1` is the starting point. In the example I have already started from `1`. You can add a loop in main to first figure out the coordinates for the starting point. Again this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: still getting the same error https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-whether-path-exist .

Comment: That's what missing in. the condition. It really helped me . I needed to add this too

Comment: I did accepted it . I guess I had some network issue here. thanx for the help :)